# Blender 2.8 Boolean inconsistencies

Tags: units

I'm trying a simple boolean add. I select the first object (sphere) then add a boolean modifier (cube).
In first attempt with sphere in position 1, the results are as expected.
[image: first attempt]

When I move the sphere to the left, and apply the modifier, the sphere disappears.
[image: second attempt]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had an object of the same name that was hidden in a different collection. When I renamed the cube the modifier worked correctly. Blender doesn't like duplicate names for objects. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the overlap threshold option. Also adding a few loopcuts or a subdivision modifier (set to Simple)  on your main object will help with your issue.